# CodeIgniter: unset all userdata, but not destroy the session

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is there a way to unset ALL userdata in a session without having to use session destroy? I'm trying to log my user out and need to unset all userdata one at a time. It's becoming tedious to keep track of all possible userdata set in session. I just want to unset everything that might have been set in userdata.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use `$this->session->sess_destroy();`, given that it does precisely what you're trying to do?

Comment: I modified my answer to better answer your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is very simple!

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

or

```
 $array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');
 $this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

I hope this helps!

**Edit: It looks like you actually don't keep track of anything in your session (kind of strange?). You could call this function I wrote up:**

```
function unset_only() {
    $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();

    foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
            $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Of course, that assumes you use the default CI session setup though.**

Comment: I don't want to accidentally leave something in userdata that shouldn't be there. I think your solution might work. Perhaps this would be good to override `unset_userdata` so that it works with a key is not passed (it'll just delete all). Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Copied from codeigniter forum:

> All it does is kills the users cookie, but the userdata will
>   remain within the session class until the end of the current request.
>   The session will be reinitialised on the next request, and there will
>   be no userdata available. Basically, all it does is severs the link
>   between the user and the server session, but the data still remains
>   until the end of the request.
>
> If it’s that much of an issue, you can do this:
>
> $this->session->userdata = array();

Answer (score 1):

I manage it please try it .

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

// write parameter your session data

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('sessiondata');
```

// if you want to session unset group then try it

```
$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.
In the latest version above code is not working.

```
$unset_array_items = array('token_id', 'last_id');
$this->session->unset_userdata($unset_array_items);
```