# Codeigniter session clear on login

Tags: codeigniter, session

I save preferences of anonymous user in sessions.The issue is that when user did login,I have to clear previous sessions and start new one(for security reasons).

It seems if I destroy session, then login function would do logout! Even though I use `set_userdata` after `sess_destroy` it cannot do login (maybe session after destruction becomes unusable).
Using `unset` acts only on a few specified sessions.Is there any way to clear all sessions of the user without such a problem?

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('id'))
        redirect($this->config->base_url());
    if($_POST)
    {
        ...
        $user=...
        if($user)
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->session->set_userdata('id',$user['id']);
            ....
        }
        else
        {
            ....    
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('...');
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509022/codeigniter-unset-all-userdata-but-not-destroy-the-session has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MaximKumpan , worked fine, please post this link as an answer.

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate strictly speaking, so I posted the excerpt from that answer below. Do try to research your questions a bit more thoroughly though, a simple re-phrase of the query works wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinitializing the session library after you run `sess_destroy()`.

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('id',$user['id']);
```

**Update:**

It appears that CI does not have a native function to clear the session without damaging it for the rest of the script runtime.

However, searching for the root cause yielded [a manual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509022/codeigniter-unset-all-userdata-but-not-destroy-the-session).

```
function unset_only() {
    $user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();

    foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
            $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't help. btw, library is loaded in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `sess_destroy` unless you are planning to redirect back again on the same url.
just use

`$this->session->set_userdata('id','')`

or you could create an `array` of the sessions you want to destroy and on its value just add a null sample

```
$test = array('session_id'=>'','session_id2'=>'');
$this->session->set_userdata($test);
```

this will make the session with names `session_id` and `session_id2` `NULL` or `FALSE`

because when you called `sess_destroy()` it destroys all the `session` the app is using. even if you try to add another session after calling it it will not add since there are no active sessions and That's why it will not work. Tried it many times, it will only work if you refresh or redirect back to the controller/method so that a new session will be created. That's how session in CI works, i don't know correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: true! but if I have a lot of items to unset and during developement I increase more session items, how can I guarantee that all items would clear. here you just clear `session_id`. but what if session includes `language`, `permissions` and other options and I dont want they mix with authenticated user. is there any way to clear all content of session in CI?