# Session is not getting unset when signing out

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have created admin panel in codeigniter. Sign in is working fine and data is also set in session. The issue is when I click on signout it doesn't clear the session data.

My controller signout function :

```
public function signout()
{
    
    $this->user_m->signout();
    redirect('admin','refresh');
}
```

`user_m` model signout function :

```
public function signout()
{
    $adminsignindata = array('loginname','adminusername','userid','role_id','loggedin');
    $this->session->unset_userdata($adminsignindata);
}
```

I don't know why session is not getting unset when I use array in `unset_userdata`.

In localhost it is working but in live not working. In live I had to unset userdata using key wise.

Comment: try `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Comment: $this->session->unset_userdata('loginname') ;  key name use

Comment: i cant use `sess_destroy` as it will destroy whole session

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509153/6309457

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar i used key vise and it worked. Thanks. But its strange why passing an array is not working?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I tried that also but when passing array in `unset_userdata` function it doesnt actually unsetting data.

Comment: what CI + PhP version are you using?

Comment: CI version 2.1.0 and PhP version 7.2.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CI 2.x** session library contains the function unset_userdata(); which works either with a string or an associative array:

> unset_userdata() can be used to remove it (the session), by passing the *session key*.
>
> This function can also be passed an *associative array of items* to
> unset.

source: [CI 2.x manual, Removing Session Data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)

below the function unset_userdata() in the session library, around line 500:

```
function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
{
    if (is_string($newdata))
    {
        $newdata = array($newdata => '');
    }

    if (count($newdata) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
        {
            unset($this->userdata[$key]);
        }
    }

    $this->sess_write();
}
```

so in case, you continue with version 2.x you need to change `$adminsignindata` into an associative array:

```
$adminsignindata = array('loginname'=>'','adminusername'=>'','userid'=>'','role_id'=>'','loggedin'=>'');
```

in **CI 3.x**, this function was changed and accepts a "normal" array, as in your code example

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use the below code it will work.
Put your session in array    

$session = [
     'user_name'    => 'msrinivas',
     'name'         => 'Srinivas'
];
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_console', $session);


unset session using array key
$this->session->unset_userdata(['logged_console']);
```

Comment: Use above code it will work